# How to fix np.prod() returning 0? I understand it can max out, but can it min out?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I'm using numpy.prod() to multiply all numbers in a list in python3. The list numbers are very small (such as 3.8226299694189604e-08) and the list is about 550 elements long. When I attempt to multiply them together, it returns 0.

> y = [0.0006468213925471674, 0.00031117360681864404, 0.0001454104738910428, 0.00030524638919498945, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 0.00016952525710158057, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 1.6172703443345647e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 0.000589117232882252, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 2.9787108915549283e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 2.290387760571247e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 0.00045522525619576915, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 9.304076646489873e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 0.0007210288342355448, 0.0005366241795681486, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 8.093595115310769e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 2.127505946313286e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 0.0003408813843883832, 0.00016575304755286858, 5.203942474584676e-06, 0.0014011932909478724, 0.00017043312646063902, 0.0001842940434681165, 6.557209485476357e-05, 2.481022813591621e-05, 0.0006236676207450345, 0.00013974006784962415, 0.0008532874130044894, 0.00013974006784962415, 0.00032145669406403673, 0.0014401033223855751, 0.0005881669010542191, 0.00024152043690288857, 0.000236890251741417, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 2.5928402823651683e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 1.835832306358118e-05, 3.534960083809872e-05, 2.199892303445638e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 5.04116727503314e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 1.0582416277687164e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 0.00016322627635050667, 7.607790595573319e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 1.3472856807159536e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.0963302752293576e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.357006813670261e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 1.508468595624559e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 1.0741590214067279e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.67882627056939e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 1.1127630036919678e-05, 2.485679401159341e-05, 1.0582416277687164e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 5.5912765360341004e-05, 5.743644164498608e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 4.432053850750466e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 6.179096379599487e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 5.203942474584676e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 4.876998412882746e-06, 6.854968001872972e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 4.58897626328819e-06, 7.68348623853211e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 8.801748140033776e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 5.743644164498608e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 1.9267213418589567e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 1.532874617737003e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.0963302752293576e-06, 3.1209924040643184e-06, 8.742507064974555e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 4.876998412882746e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 2.127505946313286e-05, 2.127505946313286e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 4.717980118527726e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 1.265290519877676e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 9.374210141610934e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 4.939033952795421e-06, 4.535438028422378e-06, 1.0369658649475164e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 1.0708098670237516e-05, 5.743644164498608e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 9.59480122324159e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 8.82588140180674e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.040524413239765e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 4.58897626328819e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 5.42221217211526e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 2.7673615173615174e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.0963302752293576e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 2.948280849656997e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 1.1621953479751645e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 9.59480122324159e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.625965013579693e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.0963302752293576e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 2.8116243030535644e-05, 5.347434590553856e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 1.2402782497074038e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.0963302752293576e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 9.59480122324159e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 4.757522558236115e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.823008447633754e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 1.0820003136516898e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 5.743644164498608e-06, 5.743644164498608e-06, 1.1449062029303026e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 1.052937681503544e-05, 1.3450963034497559e-05, 1.3450963034497559e-05, 1.3450963034497559e-05, 6.744594667095874e-06, 6.744594667095874e-06, 1.14638909256378e-05, 6.744594667095874e-06, 8.214836963026244e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 4.432053850750466e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 5.743644164498608e-06, 5.743644164498608e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 5.002680805433099e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 5.203942474584676e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 4.448953187485298e-06, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 5.347434590553856e-06, 3.67882627056939e-06, 1.508468595624559e-06, 1.8241226154070193e-05, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08, 3.8226299694189604e-08]
>
> multiplied = np.prod(y)
>
> print(multiplied)

Comment: What result would you like a "fixed" version of the code to return? `0.0` is almost certainly the closest representable float to the exact mathematical product. Note that the smallest positive representable value possible with IEEE 754 binary64 floats (which is likely what NumPy is using here) is 2**-1074, or around 5e-324. Your product is much smaller than this.

Comment: Would it help to take the logs of each number and then multiply the list together?

Comment: Yes, taking the sum of the logs instead of the product of the original values is a standard trick, but whether it helps or not really depends on what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you could give some more details? If you're computing a probability, for example, then the difference between `0.0` and the true probability here is really academic, and perhaps `0.0` is a reasonable answer already for your purposes. Alternatively, is this product going into some further calculation? If so, what?

Comment: When computing probabilities these sorts of things come up *all* the time. The standard use case is when doing a maximum likelihood fit which when computed for many values will always end up being very small. In these cases, one usually forgoes working with the probabilities directly and instead solely works in log space in which case `log(np.prod(y)) = np.log(y).sum()`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get a number that small to be stored accurately using `numpy`'s floating point numbers. So it returns 0, which is correct. Depending on what you want to do, however, some tricks can be performed to deal with this extremely small number. You should add more details to your question.

Comment: The fact that a number cannot be represented in the floating-point format `numpy` is using does not mean that a number cannot be represented. There are other ways to represent numbers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did not say or mean that it was impossible, I was just answering the OP's question, which is about why the `prod()` returns 0. Now, if the OP needs more details about anything else, it would/should have been included in their question.. I have modified my answer however to give a bit more of an explanation.